Classes of language with at least $n$ pump-able substrings
Regular languages (RLs) have a necessary condition (from the pumping lemma) that, for some $k$, if the string $|s| \geq k$ is in the language there is some splitting of $s$ into $xyz$ where $y\neq \epsilon$ and $|xy| \leq k$, then $xy^iz$ is also in the language for any $i$.
Context-free languages (CFLs) have a similar necessary condition that for some $k$, if the string if the string $|s| \geq k$ is in the language there is some splitting of $s$ into $xuywz$ where $uw\neq \epsilon$ and $|uyw| \leq k$, then $xu^iyw^iz$ is also in the language for any $i$.
RLs are Context-free so also follow the CFL condition, but the reverse does not hold.
Say we generalise this condition to have a certain number $n$ of pump-able substrings, e.g.:
For some $k$, if there is some string $|s|\geq k$ is in the language, there is some splitting of $s$ into $s_1x_1s_2x_2\ldots s_{n-1}x_{n-1}s_{n}x_{n}s_{n+1}$ where $x_1x_2\ldots x_n \neq \epsilon$ and $|x_1s_2\ldots s_nx_n| \leq k$ such that $s_1x_1^is_2x_2^i\ldots s_nx_n^is_{n+1}$ is also in the language for all $i$.
What do classes of language look like where we have this as a necessary condition for some $n$ but NOT for any number $<n$? Is there, for example, a simple way of generalising a model that generates CFLs (such as Context-Free grammars or pushdown automata) so that we get the $n=3$ version rather than $n=2$?

The problem is that even with $n=1$, I am not sure we can describe those languages, since the pumping lemma is a necessary condition, but not sufficient (meaning some non regular languages verify the pumping lemma).
